# How can one query the mempool of an Electrum server?

Tags: electrum, mempool, electrum-server

How does one go about querying a public Electrum server’s mempool? Not just for a address, but the entire mempool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. See the [protocol methods list](https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-methods.html).